# Are there any dataset available to visualise Negative Binomial Distribution?

Tags: statistics, dataset, binomial-cdf

I want to plot negative binomial distribution. 
Can anyone suggest where to get suitable dataset, that can be used for this distribution?

Comment: I am unaware of the rationale behind -1 rating for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the dataset from following link.
[image]

A given player, scoring his very first goal in forth match of a particular AFL season, can be modelled as negative binomial.